# :empty selector not working on column with anchors in some cells?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table which has a couple of columns that do not have required fields. This page has a mechanism to filter out content from the table which is being done client side and I am using jQuery to select the elements to hide however things do not appear to be working as expected. It works fine if I filter by some string however the behavior of an empty filter should leave only those rows with empty cells in that column.

Example table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="firstCol">Some text</td>
    <td class="secondCol"><a href="##">A link!</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="firstCol"></td>
    <td class="secondCol"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For the first column I'm doing something like:

```
$('table tr').find('.firstCol:not(:empty)').parent().hide();
```

This works for this column. All that would remain visible are the rows without content in the first column.

If I do:

```
$('table tr').find('.secondCol:not(:empty)').parent().hide();
```

All rows from column 2 are removed. Is there a generic way to select this to return only `<td>`s matching this behavior when they have no content? Not that it should matter but these are generated rows from a query and I have checked in the browser and the cell does not have content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your problem.  Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmP5x/1/).  It does exactly what you want it to do.

```
$('table tr').find('.firstCol:not(:empty)').parent().hide();
```

If there is content in the firstCol td, then hide the tr that contains it (including the secondCol td, no matter if it has content or not).

```
$('table tr').find('.secondCol:not(:empty)').parent().hide();
```

If there is content in the secondCol td, then hide the tr that contains it (including the firstCol td, no matter if it has content or not).

With the HTML you provided, both JS snippets end up doing the same thing.  They hide the first tr.

Comment: See, it is working the way I would expect in the fiddle. I am unsure why this isn't working in my case. Let me investigate further and I might have some more info.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work correctly in IE8 but not in Chrome 17 or Firefox 11. Wow...first time IE ever acted like I expected :P

Comment: I am running the code on FF11 and Safari5.1.  Works in both browsers perfectly.

Comment: Would you happen to be on a mac perchance? I will try again tomorrow and see if it's possibly something I'm overlooking...perhaps something is malformed and IE is letting it go while Chrome and FF are squashing it? Any alternative approaches to accomplish the same task?

Comment: In order to experiment I put the contents of the column that would match 'firstCol' in a span and the same behavior occurred. It hid all the rows rather than just the ones containing no text. In both cases, cells with no text to not get a span/anchor.

Comment: I found the answer to be a factor of non visible characters injected by my editor...I will upvote because you do have the correct approach but I will add an answer so that maybe others won't be stumped.

Answer (score 1):

While @Steve is functionally correct, that should work for all elements what was not visible in the Chrome developer tools were a number of characters which in Chrome and FireFox jQuery notices when evaluating `:empty` which Internet Explorer does not. I thought I should share what I found.

The conditional code that determined whether or not a cell should have content looked like:

```
<td class="secondCol">
   <CFIF firstColVal NEQ "">
      <a href='##' value="#firstColVal#"></a>
   </CFIF>
</td>
```

Viewing the HTML output in Chrome the cell without content showed as:

```
<td class="secondCol"></td>
```

When I copy and pasted it while inspecting it in Chrome I ended up with this:

```
<td class="secondCol">
                                      </td>
```

InternetExplorer ignored the new line and white space when considering `:empty` while Chrome and FireFox did not. This is with jQuery 1.7.1.